# compute eigenvectors of big matrix

Tags: matrix, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have an 6000*16000 matrix `D`
I need to compute  matrix `C` formed by the first `l`eigenvectors with the smallest
eigenvalues `D` ( I don't choose the right `l` until now)

what is the faster  way to compute `C`?

Comment: What have you got so far ?  How can anyone recommend a faster approach when you don't reveal your current approach or its performance ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark in fact I have no idea about this tobic 
the only way I have tried is with the matlab `eig`